How to refresh entity on @PostUpdate
My project Hibernate version 6
My project Spring Boot Version 3.2.2
For a special case, if an entity is to be updated, I want to undo the changes in some cases. Is it possible to do this during @PostUpdate?
In case of @PostUpdate when I do entityManager.refresh(entity) it does not rollback.
Custom Listener class
public class EntityListener {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public EntityListener(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return applicationContext.getBean(EntityManager.class);
    }

    @PostUpdate
    @Transactional
    public void postUpdate(Object entity) {
        getEntityManager().refresh(entity); //doesn't work
    }
}

